Spring state machine persistence does not work correctly
It seems that Spring State Machine persistence does not persist (or restore) a state machine properly if the state machine has at least four layer hierarchy.
I'm using Showcase state machine example to describe the problem.

Start the state machine.
Send event C to switch state to S211 (4th layer deep).
Persist the state machine.
Restore the state machine and send an event associated with state S211 as transition source (D, G or I), not with its ancestors.
Persist again.

Behavior for C: S11 -> S112
> RESTORED <
    [stateContext] stage=TRANSITION_START state=null
    [stateContext] stage=TRANSITION state=null
    [stateContext] stage=STATE_ENTRY state=[S0]
    [stateContext] stage=TRANSITION_START state=[S0]
    [stateContext] stage=TRANSITION state=[S0]
    [stateContext] stage=STATE_ENTRY state=[S0, S1]
    [stateContext] stage=TRANSITION_START state=[S0, S1]
    [stateContext] stage=TRANSITION state=[S0, S1]
    [stateContext] stage=STATE_ENTRY state=[S0, S1, S11]
    [stateContext] stage=STATE_CHANGED state=[S0, S1, S11]
    [stateContext] stage=STATEMACHINE_START state=[S0, S1, S11]
    [stateContext] stage=TRANSITION_END state=[S0, S1, S11]
    [stateContext] stage=STATE_CHANGED state=[S0, S1, S11]
    [stateContext] stage=STATEMACHINE_START state=[S0, S1, S11]
    [stateContext] stage=TRANSITION_END state=[S0, S1, S11]
    [stateContext] stage=STATE_CHANGED state=[S0, S1, S11]
    [stateContext] stage=STATEMACHINE_START state=[S0, S1, S11]
    [stateContext] stage=TRANSITION_END state=[S0, S1, S11]
    [stateContext] stage=STATEMACHINE_STOP state=[S0, S1, S11]
    [stateContext] stage=STATEMACHINE_START state=[S0, S1, S11]
    [stateContext] stage=EVENT_NOT_ACCEPTED state=[S0, S1, S11]
    [stateContext] stage=EVENT_NOT_ACCEPTED state=[S0, S1, S11]
    [stateContext] stage=TRANSITION_START state=[S0, S1, S11]
    [stateContext] stage=TRANSITION state=[S0, S1, S11]
    [stateContext] stage=STATE_EXIT state=[S0, S1, S11]
    [stateContext] stage=STATE_EXIT state=[S0, S1, S11]
    [stateContext] stage=STATEMACHINE_STOP state=[S11]
    [stateContext] stage=STATE_ENTRY state=[S0, S2]
    [stateContext] stage=TRANSITION_START state=[S0, S2]
    [stateContext] stage=TRANSITION state=[S0, S2]
    [stateContext] stage=STATE_ENTRY state=[S0, S2, S21]
    [stateContext] stage=TRANSITION_START state=[S0, S2, S21]
    [stateContext] stage=TRANSITION state=[S0, S2, S21]
    [stateContext] stage=STATE_ENTRY state=[S0, S2, S21, S211]
    [stateContext] stage=STATE_CHANGED state=[S0, S2, S21, S211]
    [stateContext] stage=STATEMACHINE_START state=[S0, S2, S21, S211]
    [stateContext] stage=TRANSITION_END state=[S0, S2, S21, S211]
    [stateContext] stage=STATE_CHANGED state=[S0, S2, S21, S211]
    [stateContext] stage=STATEMACHINE_START state=[S0, S2, S21, S211]
    [stateContext] stage=TRANSITION_END state=[S0, S2, S21, S211]
    [stateContext] stage=STATE_CHANGED state=[S0, S2, S21, S211]
    [stateContext] stage=TRANSITION_END state=[S0, S2, S21, S211]
> PERSISTING... <
> PERSISTED <

Behavior for G: S211 -> S0
> RESTORED <
    [stateContext] stage=TRANSITION_START state=null
    [stateContext] stage=TRANSITION state=null
    [stateContext] stage=STATE_ENTRY state=[S0]
    [stateContext] stage=TRANSITION_START state=[S0]
    [stateContext] stage=TRANSITION state=[S0]
    [stateContext] stage=STATE_ENTRY state=[S0, S1]
    [stateContext] stage=TRANSITION_START state=[S0, S1]
    [stateContext] stage=TRANSITION state=[S0, S1]
    [stateContext] stage=STATE_ENTRY state=[S0, S1, S11]
    [stateContext] stage=STATE_CHANGED state=[S0, S1, S11]
    [stateContext] stage=STATEMACHINE_START state=[S0, S1, S11]
    [stateContext] stage=TRANSITION_END state=[S0, S1, S11]
    [stateContext] stage=STATE_CHANGED state=[S0, S1, S11]
    [stateContext] stage=STATEMACHINE_START state=[S0, S1, S11]
    [stateContext] stage=TRANSITION_END state=[S0, S1, S11]
    [stateContext] stage=STATE_CHANGED state=[S0, S1, S11]
    [stateContext] stage=STATEMACHINE_START state=[S0, S1, S11]
    [stateContext] stage=TRANSITION_END state=[S0, S1, S11]
    [stateContext] stage=STATEMACHINE_STOP state=[S0, S1, S11]
    [stateContext] stage=STATEMACHINE_START state=[S0, S2, S21]
    [stateContext] stage=EVENT_NOT_ACCEPTED state=[S0, S2, S21] <-- there is no S211 anywhere
    [stateContext] stage=EVENT_NOT_ACCEPTED state=[S0, S2, S21]
    [stateContext] stage=EVENT_NOT_ACCEPTED state=[S0, S2, S21]
    [stateContext] stage=EVENT_NOT_ACCEPTED state=[S0, S2, S21]
> PERSISTING... <
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.statemachine.state.State.getId()" because the return value of "org.springframework.statemachine.StateMachine.getState()" is null
    at org.springframework.statemachine.persist.AbstractStateMachinePersister.buildStateMachineContext(AbstractStateMachinePersister.java:84) ~[spring-statemachine-core-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
    at org.springframework.statemachine.persist.AbstractStateMachinePersister.buildStateMachineContext(AbstractStateMachinePersister.java:85) ~[spring-statemachine-core-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
    at org.springframework.statemachine.persist.AbstractStateMachinePersister.buildStateMachineContext(AbstractStateMachinePersister.java:85) ~[spring-statemachine-core-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
    at org.springframework.statemachine.persist.AbstractStateMachinePersister.persist(AbstractStateMachinePersister.java:63) ~[spring-statemachine-core-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
    ...

Other details:

While in S211, sending allowed events other than D, G or I works fine.
While in S11 or S12, sending any allowed events works fine.
I think the problem has its origin somewhere during restoration of the state machine as I can't see full state [S0, S2, S21, S211] in the logs after I try to transition from S211 (above).

Spring StateMachine version: 4.0.0
I'm using RedisStateMachineContextRepository as the context repository.
I don't know if it is a bug or it just a misconfiguration. If bug, are there any workarounds, fixes or different persisters that would let me use a similar hierarchy in my project?
I tried to debug the source code but since I'm new to reactive programming, I'm not able to get the root of the problem.
My code if needed
@Configuration
class RedisConfiguration {
    @Bean("redisTemplate")
    fun redisTemplate(jedisConnectionFactory: JedisConnectionFactory): RedisTemplate<String, ByteArray> {
        return RedisTemplate<String, ByteArray>().apply {
            keySerializer = StringRedisSerializer()
            hashKeySerializer = StringRedisSerializer()
            setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory)
            afterPropertiesSet()
        }
    }
}

@Component
class RedisPersistenceConfiguration {
    @Bean("redisStateMachinePersist")
    fun redisStateMachinePersist(
        @Qualifier("redisTemplate") redisTemplate: RedisTemplate<String, ByteArray>
    ): StateMachinePersist<States, Events, String> {
        val repository = RedisStateMachineContextRepository<States, Events>(redisTemplate.connectionFactory)
        return RepositoryStateMachinePersist(repository)
    }
}

@Configuration
class StateMachinePersister(
    @Qualifier("redisStateMachinePersist")
    private val redisStatesMachinePersist: StateMachinePersist<States, Events, String>
) : RedisStateMachinePersister<States, Events>(redisStatesMachinePersist)

@RestController
class Controller(
    private val statesMachinePersist: StateMachinePersist<States, Events, String>,
    private val statesMachineFactory: StateMachineFactory<States, Events>,
    private val persister: StateMachinePersister
) {
    @PostMapping("/test/{event}")
    fun changeState(@PathVariable event: String): TestResponse {
        val stateMachineId = "test"
        val context = statesMachinePersist.read(stateMachineId)
        val machine = if (context != null) {
            persister.restore(statesMachineFactory.stateMachine, stateMachineId)
        } else {
            statesMachineFactory.getStateMachine(stateMachineId)
        }
machine.sendEvent(Mono.just(MessageBuilder.withPayload(Events.valueOf(event)).build())).blockLast()
        persister.persist(machine, stateMachineId) // <- Exception when trying to send G from S211
        return TestResponse(...)
    }
}


I implemented my own simple persister and it seems to work fine now.
@Service
class MyStateMachinePersister(
    private val redisTemplate: RedisTemplate<String, ByteArray>,
    private val stateMachineFactory: StateMachineFactory<States, Events>,
    private val kryoSerializationService: KryoStateMachineSerialisationService<States, Events>
) {

    fun persist(stateMachine: StateMachine<States, Events>, stateMachineId: String) {
        val bytes = kryoSerializationService.serialiseStateMachineContext(
            DefaultStateMachineContext(stateMachine.state?.ids?.last(), null, null, stateMachine.extendedState)
        )
        redisTemplate.opsForValue().set(stateMachineId, bytes)
    }

    fun restore(stateMachineId: String): StateMachine<States, Events> {
        val contextValue = redisTemplate.opsForValue().get(stateMachineId)
        val context = kryoSerializationService.deserialiseStateMachineContext(contextValue)
        val sm = stateMachineFactory.getStateMachine(stateMachineId)
        sm.stopReactively().block()
        sm.stateMachineAccessor.doWithAllRegions { sma ->
            sma.resetStateMachineReactively(context).block()
        }
        sm.startReactively().block()
        return sm
    }

    fun persisted(stateMachineId: String): Boolean {
        return redisTemplate.opsForValue().get(stateMachineId) != null
    }
}

